# Shortcut to adjust ggplot code to change color of all text - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, rgb, hsl

I am trying to edit my code to make all the text and labels with the following color information
RGB: (204, 14, 68)
Hex: #CC0E44
HSL: (243, 222, 109)

Here is my current code and its current output

```
ggplot(Alldata, aes(Date)) + geom_tile(aes(alpha = Recession, y = 1), 
        fill = "grey", height = Inf) + 
        scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 1),
        breaks = c(0, 1), labels = c("0" = "Expansion", "1" = "Recession"))+
        geom_line(aes(y = INFEX), col = "blue", size = .8)+ 
        ylab('Infation Expectations (%)')+
        labs(x = NULL, alpha = "Economic Cylcle", color = "Economic Variable",
        title = "Rising Inflation Expectations in 2021",
        caption = 'Cleveland Fed Model of 10-year Inflation Expectations',
        subtitle = '"Directionality Matters"')+
        theme(plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major= element_blank())
```

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1vP2.png)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Put `text = element_text(color = "#CC0E44")` as an argument to `theme()`.

Comment: Can I also use a 'family =' function to add times new roman font?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: How would I do that? I am having trouble with the ideas I have found so far.

Answer (score 0):

To set the color use this command:

```r
theme(text = element_text(color = '#CC0E44'))
```

To add another font family:

```r
install.packages("showtext", dependencies = TRUE)
library(showtext)

font_add("Times New Roman", regular = "times.ttf",bold = 'timesbd.ttf', 
italic = 'timesi.ttf', bolditalic = 'timesbi.ttf')
```

then in your plot call, inside `element_text()`, put `family = 'Times New Roman'`. And you can modify the the face by adding the `face` argument as well.